# BeautifulSoup does not pick up individual tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to set up a web scraper for the following page:
https://www.autozone.com/external-engine/oil-filter?pageNumber=1

```
#connect and download html
data = 'https://www.autozone.com/motor-oil-and-transmission-fluid/engine-oil?pageNumber=1'
uclient = urlopen(data)
pagehtml= uclient.read()
uclient.close()
articles = bs(pagehtml,'html.parser')

#separate data by shop items
containers = articles.find_all('div',{'class' : 'shelfItem'})
```

However, when I try to grab the price, nothing is found:

```
containers[0].find_all('div',{'class':'price'})
```

...while inspecting the website with my browser shows the following:

```
<div class="price" id="retailpricediv_663653_0" style="height: 85px;">Price: <strong>$8.99</strong><br>
```

How can I grab that $8.99?

Thanks

Comment: From having a quick look at the source, and fiddling in the console, although there are divs with a class of `price`, none are inside a div with class `shelfItem` (although the latter do exist). It appears that you want `shelfItemDetails` instead of simply `shelfItem`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both, but in either case, I just get an empty div (e.g. id="retailpricediv_663650_2" for the first article), with no price inside

Answer (score 2):

You can get required data prices by direct call to api:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.autozone.com/rest/bean/autozone/diy/commerce/pricing/PricingServices/retrievePriceAndAvailability?atg-rest-depth=2'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'}
data = {'arg1': 6997, 'arg2':'', 'arg3': '663653,663636,663650,5531,663637,663639,644036,663658,663641,835241,663645,663642', 'arg4': ''}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()

for item in response['atgResponse']:
    print(item['retailPrice'])
```

Output:

```
8.99
8.99
10.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
8.99
```

To create `data` dict you need to pass *store number* as `arg1` and *list of each item id* as `arg3`...

You can get `arg1` value once, but `arg3` should be extracted on each page

```
page_url = 'https://www.autozone.com/external-engine/oil-filter?pageNumber=1'
r = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
source = bs(r.text)
arg1 = source.find('div',{'id' : 'myStoreNum'}).text
arg3 = ",".join([_id['id'].strip('azid') for _id in source.find_all('div',{'class' : 'categorizedShelfItem'})])
```

so now you can define `data` without hardcoding values:

```
data = {'arg1': arg1, 'arg2':'', 'arg3': arg3, 'arg4': ''}
```

To get values from next page just change `pageNumber=1` to `pageNumber=2` in `page_url` - the rest code remains the same...

Answer (score 2):

I think the prices are loaded by javascript so will need a method like selenium to ensure values present (or API call as shown in other answer!)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.autozone.com/motor-oil-and-transmission-fluid/engine-oil?pageNumber=1")
products = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.prodName')
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.price[id*=retailpricediv]')

productList = []
priceList = []
for product, price in zip(products,prices):
    productList.append(product.text)
    priceList.append(price.text.split('\n')[0].replace('Price: ',''))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':productList,'Price':priceList})
print(df)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can peel the same apple in different ways. Here is another approach using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from contextlib import closing

with closing(webdriver.Chrome()) as driver:
    driver.get("https://www.autozone.com/external-engine/oil-filter?pageNumber=1")
    for items in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[typeof='Product']"):
        price = items.find_element_by_css_selector('.price > strong').text
        print(price)
```

Output:

```
$8.99
$8.99
$10.99
$8.99
$8.99
```

and so on ....